# Access to every iframe child

Tags: javascript, iframe, children

I'm working with a client proyect which is working with lot's of iframes inside others.
The problem is that I want to add an addEventListener in all iframes automatically from the absolute parent document, an example schema would be this:

```
Document: iframe1, iframe2
Iframe1: iframe1.1, iframe1.2
Iframe1.1: iframe.1.1.1, iframe 1.1.2
```

I want to simulate something like this:

```
iframes[i].contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[i]
```

I wrote this code, but I have an "undefined" error:

```
 window.onload=function(){
    eventoIframe(document,null,1);
}



var eventoIframe=function(target,prev_target,lvl){
    console.log('Ejecuto funcion por '+lvl+' vez');
    var iframes=target.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    if(lvl>2){
        var iframes=prev_target.target.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    }
    if(iframes.length>0){
        for(var i=0;i<=iframes.length-1;i++){
            var iframe=iframes[i].contentWindow;
            iframe.addEventListener("click",function(event){
                console.log('click on:', event.target)
            },false);


            eventoIframe(iframe.document,target,lvl+1);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the mistake, I don't know why I wanted to know the prev target hehe
The solution is

```
window.onload=function(){
    eventoIframe(document);
}


var eventoIframe=function(target){
    var iframes=target.getElementsByTagName('iframe');

    if(iframes.length>0){
        for(var i=0;i<=iframes.length-1;i++){
            var iframe=iframes[i].contentWindow;
            iframe.addEventListener("click",function(event){
                //code to be execute on each iframe
            },false);
            eventoIframe(iframe.document);
        }
    }

}
```